# If expression variables inside if block

Tags: python, syntax

This is a common idiom:

```
if foo.get("bar"):
    bar = foo.get("bar")
    # DO something with bar
```

Instead I want to say something like

```
if foo.get("bar") as bar:
    # DO something with bar
```

Is there some way to say this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not.

```
bar = foo.get('bar')
if bar:
   ...
del bar
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such syntax, no. For dictionaries, you'd usually use a membership test instead:

```
if 'bar' in foo:
    bar = foo['bar']
```

This is what most beginning Python programmers think `if foo.get('bar')` does, but an empty value (e.g. `{'bar': 0}`) would also be false here.

For the edge case where you really want to skip both missing keys *and* empty values, you'd use `.get()` **once**:

```
bar = foo.get('bar')
if bar:
    #
```

The latter could preferable if you are going to store the value in a local variable anyway, but you'd test for `is not None` to allow for other falsey values:

```
bar = foo.get('bar')
if bar is not None:
    #
```

There is no no need to call `.get()` twice, certainly not when you already determined that the `'bar'` key exists.

Comment: -1 because nothing in the question says that `foo` is a `dict` or other object implementing `__contains__`, and even if it *were* a dict the logic you've shown isn't equivalent to the original logic.

Comment: @wim: Yet the call `.get()` method once advice somehow doesn't apply? For dictionaries the logic is **exactly** the same.

Comment: No, the logic is not the same.  Consider `foo = {'bar': ''}`, in your case the block `if 'bar' in foo:` will be entered.  It won't be entered with `if foo.get("bar"):`

Comment: @wim: right, that's an edge cases that would not be handled the same, indeed. **Most** cases where I see users use `dict.get()` in an `if` test should actually be replaced with a membership test *because* the empty value would result in the `if` test not passing, however.

Comment: @wim: expanded to handle the edge case explicitly.

Comment: OK, --1.  In the last block, it is still not possible to distinguish between a `None` returned as default for a `dict.get` on a missing key and a `None` which *was* the value of an existing key.  However, it is not needed to make this distinction in the context of the question

Comment: @wim: Nope, and you can use a different sentinel in that case; I prefer `sentinel = object()`, `bar = foo.get('bar', sentinel)` myself as that is more explicit than, say, reusing one of the Python built-in singletons.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an hack, but this works.

```
In [17]: if [bar for bar in [foo.get('bar')] if bar]:
   ....:     print bar
```

Will not work in python3

Comment: It exploits a bug in python 2 and won't work in python 3 though

Comment: @wim Thanks, added that to the answer.

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension for its side effects, **please**. I'd certainly reject code like this in a code review. I've downvoted this because people really, really should not rely on list comprehension variables leaking into the local namespace.

Comment: I mentioned that it's a hack, which should tell OP that he probably should not do it. I would not use it. Although it is the only way to do what OP wanted, as far as i know. Assigning and then doing the test as the two other answer's suggest, would indeed be the better option.

Comment: And if nothing else, OP learned about the bug. Which could prevent a nasty gotcha later.

Comment: +1 anyway for showing that it *is* actually possible